# SSH one processor from the other processor without network interface

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, ipc

I have two processors on the same die. One is an ARM processor running
linux and another is a non-ARM processor running linux operating
system (Proprietary Proc).  We do not have any medium like Network
Interface or PCI or USB running between the two processors, except 1GB
of shared memory.

We would want to be able to SSH the non-ARM processor on the ARM
processor and mount FS.

I was wondering if I can get some suggestion on what would be a
possible way to establish this communication between the processors.

As a  matter of concept, I just happen to write a small network driver
that talks over the shared memory and could transfer packets between
the two. But this does not help me with my bigger use case of being
able to SSH one processor from the other.

Greatly appreciate any suggestion in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path, this is not uncommon way to approach on the same die or on the same board with a shared memory between processors.

You should only need to implement the physical layer, replace a NIC or take a NIC driver and implement the rings (circular buffer) in ram instead of talking to a card.  Head and tail pointers, you can burn ram and make all the packet slots the same size, larger than the largest you support (basically either 2Kbytes or say 10Kbytes if you support jumbo 10K is easy to compute without a multiply, or use a multiply whatever).  Or you can have a table structure or a linked listy thing if you want to conserve memory at the price of a little bit more computation.

Sometimes that layer deals with the mac layer checksums but you shouldnt be doing anything protocol related, doesnt matter if it is ssh or ftp or http or whatever that is way above this layer.

Answer (score -1):

Create a virtual serial port between the two cores with a small userspace program

- make sure PTY support (`CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS` or `CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS`) and `CONFIG_PPP_ASYNC` is configured in both kernels
- write a userspace program that

  - `mmap`s a chunk of the shared memory into userspace
  - sets up a ring buffer for sending
  - finds the other side's ring buffer for receiving
  - copies everything from `stdin` into the sending buffer
  - and from the receiving buffer to `stdout`
- start `pppd` on both cores with the `pty` option, and your program as the `script` parameter

Now you should be able to `ping` one core from the other. If that works, start `sshd` or any network protocol daemon you like.